# Changing font of a list python

Tags: python, list, tkinter, fonts

Say I have some code that makes a list into a 4 by 4 1d array:

```
nlist = [2,2,4,8, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0]
def drawBoard():
    count = 0
    for i in range(16):
        print(nlist[i], end = ' ')
        count += 1
        if count == 4:
            print("")
            count = 0
    print("") 
drawBoard()
```

How can I change all the fonts in this list into size 26. I tried doing font = 'times 26' but I don't know where to put it or if that command needs tkinter.

Comment: Manipulating things like font are often very terminal specific. You'll likely need to use a library like curses, or try ANSI codes. There may be a code for font adjustment.

Comment: I don't want to use curses. If it doesn't work without any modules I just want a way to use tkinter. If I initialize terminal a lot of my other code will get messed up.

Comment: That looks like a long way to print a list in a grid. Why not something like `for i in range(0, 16, 4): print(*nlist[i:i+4])` ?

Comment: What does this have to do with tkinter? Tkinter can't control the font used in a print statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your last question, yes you need tkinter. Import `from tkinter import *` or you could use `import TkFont`

Answer (score 0):

In tkinter the fonts are defined by using a tuple so. If you are wanting to change the font of everything in the list. You would have to for loop through all of the elements and say something like:

text[i].font=("Verdana", 26)

Comment: what form of tkinter would i call

Comment: when I tried to do this it gives me an error `'int' object has no attribute 'font'`